# Is it possible to uniquely identify matrix $B$ if $C=BAB$ and under the following terms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

$A$ is known and diagonal, $C$ is known and symmetric and $B$ is symmetric. All matrices are positive semi-definite and of full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that $A$ is invertible, since otherwise, the answer is a clear no.
Rewrite the equation as $A^{1/2}CA^{1/2}=(A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^2$, where $A^{1/2}$ is the unique positive definite square root of $A$.
But then we must have $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}=(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})^{1/2}$,
and hence $B=A^{-1/2}(A^{1/2}CA^{1/2})^{1/2}A^{-1/2}$.

Comment: If i follow correctly, it means that it is sufficient for A to be positive definite and i don't need it to be diagonal right? @Harald

Comment: Yes, that is right.